# Ionic / Cordova push notification using Parse

Tags: cordova, mobile, parse-platform, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins

Can some one please give me a solid push notification solution using ionic framework and Parse.com ?

I have a cross platform app which built on top of ionic framework and Parse.

My app is basically community app which users can post and comment. It requires to send a push notification to author once someone comment to the post.

I saw few examples using subscribe / channel model but if do it this way I need to create huge amount of channels. I am not sure if this is appropriate approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still in need of a solution, you can try my https://github.com/taivo/parse-push-plugin .

I got tired of the lengthy and error prone process of messing with AndroidManifest, java, and objective C so I automated most of it into that plugin.

All you need to do is

```
$ cordova add https://github.com/taivo/parse-push-plugin
```

Then set a few `config.xml` parameters to indicate server url and appId. It works for both parse-server and the outgoing parse.com

Comment: plugin : cordova add https://github.com/taivo/parse-push-plugin does not work with ionic 4 or above :(